# what is the default timeout for a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, web, weblogic

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html
"Destroy... is only called once all threads within the servlet's service method have exited or after a timeout period has passed"

What is the default time out for the destroy method? How do I change it?
I am running weblogic and in the administration console each deployment module has configurations. Is the timeout mentioned above what weblogic admin console calls Session Invalidation Interval or Session Timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice the destroy() method will only be called when your web application is unloaded by the application server. This is when the server is shut down or when the application is undeployed.

Note that the session timeout is something completely different. It specifies how long a user session is kept alive without interaction by the user.

Comment: So what is the time out period they mention in the docs? the part "or after a timeout period has passed"

Comment: I believe an application server is allowed to destroy a servlet after a specific time (the timeout). However I don't know of any application server doing this and servlets exist until the application they belong to is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no timeout for servlet. It exist till the web application is alive. Yes there is a default timeout of every session, refer to ur server documentation for default session timeout. You can overwrite it.